# it {should_not be_valid} and @user.should_not be valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm learning rails and rspec, and don't undestand the difference between these two codes:

in my spec/models/user_spec.rb I have:

```
describe User do$
  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
  subject {@user}
```

Now I check name format:

```
describe "when name has wrong format" do
  it "should not be valid" do    
    names = %w[%marcin ??? 123 ___123 ___] 
    names.each do |invalid_name|   
      @user.name = invalid_name      
      it{should_not be_valid}        
    end
  end
end
```

it's not working but when I use `@user.should_not be_valid` instead of `it{should_not be_valid}` it works ok, I don't undestand why as I have `subject {@user}` so I thought `it {should`  means the same as `@user.should`

Comment: Why do you have calls to `it` inside another `it` ? Also, you could use `let` instead of using `@user`. Probably the reason why it doesn't work is because `@user`'s are evaluated in different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
describe User do
  subject do
    User.new(name: name, email: "user@example.com")
  end

  describe "#name" do  
    context "Just Numbers" do
      let(:name) { "123" }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Used example from here: http://benscheirman.com/2011/05/dry-up-your-rspec-files-with-subject-let-blocks